# Export Screenshots UIAutomation

Tags: ios, macos, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

With captureScreenWithName I can take a screenshot of the current screen. But are they saved in a directory on the mac somewhere ? Or are they only in the log messages?

If not, is there a way to export them to a directory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the red button on the top left corner, or run Instruments from command line. You can set the log directory in the bottom left part (when it is set to visible by the corresponding view button right from the timer). If the script is run with the play button at the bottom, the log appears in the Instruments only. (No copy and hard to save screenshots.)